# How to add value from Android app to sql database?

Tags: android, android-database, android-developer-api

I am getting these error of SQLiteException while making an app like employee tracker and basically it does not adding the data in the database. 
I am making this app using eclipse and sql database.

the error:
1. Here is the error sheet: -

2. [Database Helpler class attached below : ]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx5KU.png)

3. [Add employees class attached here :]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf0OY.png)

4. [SQL Database Create Table Query here : ]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IimO.jpg)

Comment: The error should be pretty clear. What exactly don't you understand about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your table is missing the column "Pass" from the error. Possible Typo?

You should post more details with your questions including your code which shows where you are inserting the object and the attributes associated with

Comment: This should've been a comment not an answer. I can understand that you are not eligible for writing comments yet, but it's best to not risk being down-voted for these sort of mistakes.

Comment: I have edited this post now please find the attached document and help me out through this error.